# .bnd files have errors when building in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, osgi, apache-felix, bnd

When I'm building my project in IntelliJ, I get errors for each of my .bnd files (I have no other types of errors).

I started working on a new project which works without any problems for my colleagues (which are too busy to help me do the setup). 
What I've done so far:
- got the code and imported it as a maven project in IntelliJ (no errors)
- clean installed it from terminal (no errors)
- build the project from IntelliJ (425 errors - around 2 per .bnd file)
 
- I tried disabling the OSGi plugins (dmServerSupport and Spring OSGi)
- I tried disabling the Inspection OSGi profile
- I tried adding the file in the Compiler -> Excludes (still builds it)

***What can I do to get rid of all those errors?***

My OSGi Manifest (from  looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Goodies
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.....osgi.goodies
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: ...
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.7.0",
 org.osgi.service.component.annotations;version="1.2.0",
 org.osgi.service.event;version="1.3.0",
 org.osgi.service.packageadmin;version="1.2.0"
```

**For example, I have this .bnd file:**

```
-classpath: target/classes 
-dsannotations: *
Include-Resource: README.HTML
Private-Package: com.....pubsub.impl
Export-Package: com.....pubsub
-dsannotations: *
```

For the file from above, I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error:osgi: [pubsub] Invalid Manifest header: -classpath, pattern=[A-Za-z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9_]+
Error:osgi: [pubsub] Invalid Manifest header: -dsannotations, pattern=[A-Za-z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

**Another example:**

```
-classpath: target/classes
-dsannotations: * 
Include-Resource: README.HTML
Private-Package: com.....security.thread.impl
Export-Package: com.....security.thread
Import-Package: oracle.jdbc;version=0,\
    *
```

Building the project containing the .bnd file from above, will result in the following error:

```
Error:osgi: [security.thread] Exception: java.io.IOException: invalid header field
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:406)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder.build(Builder.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.osgi.jps.build.BndWrapper.doBuild(BndWrapper.java:262)
    at org.jetbrains.osgi.jps.build.BndWrapper.build(BndWrapper.java:192)
    at org.jetbrains.osgi.jps.build.OsgiBuildSession.doBuild(OsgiBuildSession.java:211)
    at org.jetbrains.osgi.jps.build.OsgiBuildSession.build(OsgiBuildSession.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.osgi.jps.build.OsmorcBuilder.build(OsmorcBuilder.java:54)
    at org.jetbrains.osgi.jps.build.OsmorcBuilder.build(OsmorcBuilder.java:33)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTarget(IncProjectBuilder.java:1023)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1065)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:956)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.access$500(IncProjectBuilder.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder$BuildParallelizer.lambda$queueTask$0(IncProjectBuilder.java:927)
```

Comment: Does it help if you disable [Osmorc](https://i.imgur.com/qH1Onj1.png) plug-in?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Disabling Osmorc, solved my probelm.